# Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I have a parent component contact form, using react-hook-form. I want to make a test for this component using react testing library. When i try to submit I have got this error:

> Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
> Expected number of calls: 1
> Received number of calls: 0Jest

```
describe("Form", () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn();

  const renderForm = () => {
    const Wrapper = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
      const formMethods = useForm();
      return <FormProvider {...formMethods}>{props.children}</FormProvider>;
    };
    customRender(
      <Wrapper>
        <ContactForm onSubmit={onSubmit} /> //error is here
      </Wrapper>,
      {
        withRouter: true,
      }
    );
  };

  it("successful submit", () => {
    renderForm();
    const emailInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /email/i })
    const fNameInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /fname/i });
    const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /submit/i });

    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(fNameInput).toBeInTheDocument();


    fireEvent.input(emailInput, "abc@abc.com");
    fireEvent.input(fNameInput, "Alex");
    fireEvent.click(submitButton);

    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); //error is here
  });
});
```

**Component**

```
export function ContactForm({ onSubmit }: ContactFormProps) {

  const methods = useForm<FormSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
  });
  const { handleSubmit, reset } = methods;
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormSchemaType> = data => {
    ...
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
          <FormWrapper>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              ....
            </form>
          </FormWrapper>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you able to share a code sandbox example? Would help trying to debug

Comment: `ContactForm` does not take any prop, so passing `onSubmit` as prop in your test will do nothing.
As `onSubmit` is declared inside the `ContactForm` component, it means you don't need to explicitly check that is was called, you rather need to check the things that are visible from the outside of the `ContactForm` component. If `onSubmit` makes an http request for example, you could make sure the request was sent correctly.